# Is there a reason not to delete every comment to reduce stress?

Tags: needy-streamer-overload

During a stream you can reduce Ame's stress by deleting hateful comments. However, there doesn't seem to be a penalty for deleting positive comments.

If I want to reduce Ame's stress, is there any reason not to delete every comment any time she streams?

Comment: Maybe a matter of wasted time?